# Format a number with a variable number of digits in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, format

Here's a "simple" question (I think):

How can I format a number as text with a variable number of digits? Something like:

```
Dim N as Integer
Dim INPUT as Integer: INPUT = 341
Dim OUPUT as String

OUTPUT = Format(INPUT, "00...0")
```

Where `"00...0"` has `N` digits. For instance, if `N = 7`, I want `OUTPUT = "0000341"`. Can I do something like this on `VBA`? I can't find a solution for it... Thanks.

Comment: `OUTPUT = Format(INPUT, Application.Rept("0",N))`

Comment: @ScottCraner, so simple! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a simple function to achieve this:

```
Public Function FormatToLength(number As Long, length As Long) As String
    Dim returnValue As String
    
    returnValue = Application.Rept("0", length) & number
    returnValue = Right(returnValue, length)
    
    FormatToLength = returnValue
End Function
```

Output:

```
Debug.Print FormatToLength(341, 7)
0000341
```

This creates a length of repeated `0` and appends the number onto the end.  It then uses `Right` to reduce the size of the return to the desired length.

Comment: Thanks. It's an elegant solution!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way not dependent upon the Application object:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
   MsgBox FormatToLength(341, 7)
End Sub

Private Function FormatToLength(ByVal Value As Variant, ByVal Length As Long) As String
   FormatToLength = Format(Value, String(Length, "0"))
End Function
```

Comment: Even more elegant IMO :-)

Comment: This should be the obvious answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can't be the best way to do it, but here's a simple way:

```
Dim N as Integer 
Dim input_value as Integer
Dim OUPUT as String

Dim formatstring as String

N = 4
input_value = 341

'assumes N is an integer > 0
For i = 1 to N
    formatstring = formatstring + "0"
Next i

OUTPUT = Format(input_value, formatstring)
```

Comment: `&` should be used to concatenate, not `+`.